# Is $\partial_k g_{ij}=\partial_j g_{ik} $?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

I Found the following identity:
$\partial_k g_{ij}=\partial_j g_{ik} $ ?
or at least that is what it looks that it is being used.
g is a riemannian metric by the way.

[image]

**Why is it  true? .I know the metric is symmetric , but this doesn't make sense to me.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is not equal. What they wrote is simply because the summation is over both $k$ and $j$, so they have split up the sum and relabelled indices.

More explicitly, if $b^{kj}$ is symmetric, then
\begin{align}
2a_{jk}b^{jk}&=a_{jk}b^{jk}+a_{jk}b^{jk}\tag{obvious}\\
&=a_{jk}b^{jk}+a_{kj}b^{kj}\tag{relabel dummy indices}\\
&=a_{jk}b^{jk}+a_{kj}b^{jk}\tag{$b$ symmetric}\\
&=(a_{jk}+a_{kj})b^{jk}.
\end{align}
In your case, apply this with $b^{kj}=\dot{\gamma}^k\dot{\gamma}^j$ and $a_{jk}=g_{ij,k}$ ($i$ is fixed).

Answer (score 3):

No, $g_{ij,k}$ and $g_{ik,j}$ are in general not equal.

What is used here is that if $s^{ij}$ is a symmetric tensor, and $t_{\alpha ij}$ any tensor, then
$$
t_{\alpha ij} s^{ij} 
= t_{\alpha ji} s^{ji}
= t_{\alpha ji} s^{ij}.
$$